# Editing video frame by frame

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I want to create a video by merging subsequently added .png files and by giving them differing frame durations. Can I or if I can how may I achieve this editing?

> Reference video: https://youtu.be/aLfXCkFQtXw

Comment: Welcome to Blender.se. Load a png sequence into the video-sequence-editor. Then select it and press ***Y***. You will be prompted for an initial duration. Input any values. The frames will then be split into individual strips. You can move the individual strips around and edit their length individually.

Comment: Thank you for both warm greeting and answer. Your solution is exactly what I was looking for